# The specified application identifier GUID is invalid or does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Im trying to install a provider hosted app. I have registered the app on /layouts/appregnew.aspx and inserted the generated clientid and client secret web.config of my provider web and then deployed it to the provider url.

I have also created a package and added it to our appcatalog

When I try to add my new addin on /_layouts/viewlsts.aspx->Add->addin and click on my app I get the error message

The specified application identifier  is invalid or does not exist.

Im guessing that SP somehow checks on the registered provider host url for the client Id and that I have done something wrong on the provider side... any idea how to diagnos this further?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `ClientId` to **web.config** & **AppManifest.xml**.
In Web.config,

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="CLIENT_ID" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="CLIENT_SECRET" />
  </appSettings>
```

In AppManifest,

```
<AppPrincipal>
 <RemoteWebApplication ClientId="CLIENT_ID" />
</AppPrincipal>
```

Check this [link](http://bishwadebdey.blogspot.in/2016/01/step-by-step-creation-of-provider.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue in a SharePoint On-Premise environment, try to register the app id to the farm with PowerShell script below:

```
$publicCertPath = "C:\AppCerts\HighTrustSampleCert.cer"
$appId = "cbd25585-947e-4b9d-8686-ed695101ed9a"
$spurl ="https://mycompany.com/"
$spweb = Get-SPWeb $spurl
$realm = Get-SPAuthenticationRealm -ServiceContext $spweb.Site
$certificate = Get-PfxCertificate $publicCertPath
$fullAppIdentifier = $appId + '@' + $realm
New-SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer -Name "TheaterCompany" -Certificate $certificate -RegisteredIssuerName $fullAppIdentifier
$appPrincipal = Register-SPAppPrincipal -NameIdentifier $fullAppIdentifier -Site $spweb -DisplayName "TheaterCompany"
Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission -Site $spweb -AppPrincipal $appPrincipal -Scope Site -Right FullControl
```

More information from here:
[SharePoint 2013 Provider-hosted Apps: The specified application identifier is invalid or does not exist](http://srichallagolla.blogspot.sg/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-apps-specified.html)